# How to preserve orientation during a popup?

Tags: android, popup, screen-orientation

I am using menu in an activity to display a popup window.
The problem is that when the orientation is changed, the popup window disappears and the activity screen is shown again.

(It happens because when the orientation is changed the Activity is started again)

i want that the activity doesnt start again and after orientation change the popup window doesnt vannish.

Answer (score 0):

please chenge activity in manifest file 
put in activity below code

```
android:configChanges="orientation"
```

Comment: I have done that...
Also I overrided the method


@Override
 public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
  
   super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
   
   //setContentView(R.layout.messagedisp);
 }


But still nothing helped......please let me know what needds to be written within the method "onConfigurationChanged" ...to stop the activity from restarting again

Answer (score 0):

Please make the following changes to manifest where you defined your activity

add this lines:

> android:screenOrientation="landscape" or
>   android:screenOrientation="portrait"

Comment: but doing this fixes the screenOrientation

Comment: When orientation changes android starts new activity so your pop window will disappear if you fix your orientation it will not happen!

Comment: but the screen gets fixed...so the display does not change...and to read the text ..one would require to tilt his head :P :P

Is there a way to stop the restart after orientation change

Comment: I would suggest you that you override `onStart()` method and in that you can pop your window..